# Правильное согласование сказуемого

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика

Из газетного заголовка в Интернете:

**Если жить осталось месяц**

А можно написать: остался месяц?

Если да, как можно объяснить разницу, сославшись на правила?

Чувствую, что можно, но правило найти не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **Если жить осталось месяц.**

Подлежащее ― жить, сказуемое ― **осталось (ср.р.)**, месяц ― обстоятельство (как долго?).

1) Аналогичный пример с инфинитивом в роли подлежащего: *Его **делом** **было** **опекать** младших **и заботиться** о старших.* Сказуемое в форме ср.р.

2) Сравнить: **Остался месяц** на все дела.

Подлежащее ― месяц, сказуемое ― остался (м.р.)

3) Таким образом, форма ***месяц*** может быть подлежащим (И.п.) и обстоятельством времени (В.п.).

4) Примеры: До конкурса **остался месяц** с небольшим. **Мы** бы охотно **остались** здесь  еще **месяц**.